# How to create a regex for checking specific time range

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation, time

I want check string of time to be `<= 09:00`. 
This means checking for either 2 conditions

```
1. Hrs part lies between 0-8 and minutes part between 0-59
2. Hrs part is 09 and minutes part is 0
```

Can anyone please give the regex for this. The pattern I am matching is a string eg. `"07:50", "9:00", "10:15"`. These are not in time format.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of Regex, can you use C# DateTime to perform the comparison? This keeps your code strongly typed. If you have the date in a String format, you can parse it into a DateTime object using:

```
DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)
```

You can then use the GreaterThan and LessThan operators to compare to the specific dates/times you have.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx#Y69

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```
/^0?([0-8]:[0-5][0-9]|9:00)$/
```